# Exception handling in C - catching native C crash from Java JNI

Tags: c, exception, java-native-interface

I'm a Java programmer writing a JNI application which calls native C code. What I want is to detect native program crash from Java code that calls the native code.

I know that there is no exception handling in C but just curious whether I can write dangerous codes "safely" inside try-catch block in Java (e.g.code that may contain bad pointer in runtime or file not found cases). In that case the code will crash, but I was looking for a safe way to report it.

Comment: You can handle segmentation faults( SIGSEGV signals) , but your program is in a bad place, once you get one anyway.

Comment: Who says that you can handle exceptions in C? You just have to build it yourself instead of relying on pre-defined code.

Comment: @JonahNelson Why would you have to write your own code? Have you ever heard of libraries.

Comment: @self. Yes The program may be in the bad place, I just want to report it safely.

Comment: @giga Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/ and possibly http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/.

Comment: @self. Yes, however...it's not like some languages which wrap behind-the-scenes exception handling in to the compiler and cause problems with people who want to change the behavior.

Comment: FWIW, you can `throw` from the JNI layer for non-fatal errors (e.g. file not found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're taking the wrong approach. As a language C is not a place where *"it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission."* You *must* ask for permission in C, though in the event of a disaster, you can certainly do some cleanup:

You should look into **[signal handling](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)**.

When you do something like

```
int *a = NULL;
int b = *a;    //segfault
```

Your program will receive SIGSEGV, which will force your program to quit, unless you have installed a signal handler.

Most unhandled signals will cause program termination, and most can be caught (SIGKILL for example cannot be caught).

This allows you to do some cleanup.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

void myhandler(int signal){
    printf("oh noes...\n");
}
int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, myhandler);
    int *a = NULL;
    int b = *a;    //segfault
    return 0;
}
```

None of this is recommended though.  You *MUST* know the contents of your pointers at all times.  Otherwise, giants will raze your village.

EDIT: the `signal()` function is suggested as *deprecated*. New code should use `[sigaction()][2]` instead.  This example uses `signal()` for its simplicity.

Comment: Can you explain what does the line `typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);` do?

Comment: That's the typedef for the function pointer that `signal()` takes as it's second argument.  It doesn't need to be there at all.  It's just a reminder to show what your handler should look like.  I'll comment it out

Comment: Thaks @ldrumm. By writing "program will be terminated" you meant the entire program, i.e. the java program which calls native code, right? Then there is not much to do. But if only I could catch and return from the native program, my java program will be saved, and basically I want to keep my java program running even if the native code crashes.

Comment: @giga I don't know much about how the signals will work across language bindings, so this is very likely to result in some nasty surprises. I'm curious why this C module is so likely to segfault?

Comment: @ldrumm the thing is, the c module was written by many people from my organization at different times, so I'm trying to be safe to protect my java program from possible crashes.

Comment: @giga The cautious approach is good. You may be interested to hear about SetUnhandledExceptionFilter which will likely prevent the JNI-C code from killing your main thread in the event of a signal. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html#gbzdi

Answer (score 2):

No you can't reasonably detect a native crash from Java. If such a crash happens, your program is likely to be killed before you have a chance to catch it.

What you can do is to check for return codes. Any decently written C library will return you an error code if it fails (note that's different from crash). You can use those codes and translate them in Java exceptions if you wish to.

For crashes, you could use the "signal" APIs, though it's not as straight forward as it looks: if you actually caught a crash, then there's not much you could be doing as the entire program memory may have been corrupted. I'd recommend against it if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't really have exceptions. It has two things which play a similar role, but which are vastly different from one another: signals and error codes.

Let's consider error codes first. When a function call in C fails, it will typically signal this failure to the caller by returning an error code, or by returning a placeholder value (e.g, 0, -1, or NULL) and setting an error in `errno`, or storing it in a location that can be retrieved by calling another method. No special effort is required to handle these exceptions. Simply check the return values of functions, e.g.

```
FILE *fh = fopen("example", "r");
if (fh == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
// do things with fh...
```

Signals, on the other hand, are used in C to denote really unusual situations, such as an attempt to execute invalid code or dereference a bad pointer, or other external conditions like the user pressing control-C to terminate your program. You can attempt to handle some such signals using the [`signal()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) function, but the ones you've described, like a bad pointer, typically indicate that the process is screwed up in a rather permanent way, so allowing them to terminate the process is usually the correct solution.

If you are indeed running code that is prone to triggering segmentation faults, it would be wise to run it in a separate process, rather than allowing it to potentially corrupt the state of a Java runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of running a separate process. I think I'll go with this instead of the JNI approach.